# Boolean Truth Table by using Python

Tags: python

I am so new to Python, so I really need help with this question. I tried so many time, but can't get it. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

```
def xor(a,b):
      return (a and not b) or (not a and b)
```

**Write a function that returns the truth table for xor in dictionary form. You should be using xor() inside the function below**

```
def xorTruthTable():

 return {}
```

The output should be like this:

The truth table for "and" in dictionary form is

```
{(False, False) : False, \
(False, True)  : False, \
(True,  False) : False, \
(True,  True)  : True}
```

Comment: "I tried so many time" please show some of those tries. We can give you hints as to why they fail. Since this is homework, you shouldn't expect more than hints.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a nested loop. We'll loop through all the possible values of `a` (in this case, `False` and `True`), and for each of those we'll again loop through all the possible values of `b`. Whatever code we write in the inner loop will get run for every possible combination of `a` and `b`.

We'll keep track of a table (a `dict`, or `{}`) to hold these values. For each combination of `a` and `b`, we'll add the tuple `(a, b)` as a key, and `xor(a, b)` as the value for that key. Then we can just return the dictionary.

```
def truth_table():
    table = {}
    for a in [False, True]:
        for b in [False, True]:
            table[(a, b)] = xor(a, b)
    return table
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concise solution using `itertools.product` to generate the four possible input pairs and a dictionary comprehension to create the dictionary from them. `operator.xor` is a library function that happens to do the same as your `xor` function

```
{(i, j): operator.xor(i, j) for i, j in itertools.product((False, True), repeat=2)}
# Output:
# {(False, False): False, (False, True): True, (True, False): True, (True, True): False}
```

Comment: The nice thing about this solution is that it is easy to extend it to constructing truth tables of more than 2 variables.

Answer (score 0):

A 1-line solution using Python's `^` operator:

```
{(a,b): a^b for a in (True,False) for b in (True,False)}
```

If you wanted to use your `xor()`:

```
{(a,b): xor(a,b) for a in (True,False) for b in (True,False)}
```

Either would evaluate to

```
{(False, True): True, (True, False): True, (False, False): False, (True, True): False}
```